# Android implicit intents validation

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application I save data into Excel files and offer user to:

1. Open saved Excel file on the device;
2. Show file in file manager (containing folder).
3. Send file attached by Email (actually open email client and attach the file).

Everything seemes to work fine on my device but the question is:

- How to validate these implicit intents?
- Say if there is no Excel viewer/file manager/email client available?
- How should I predict it?
- Should I add any other validation?

**CODE**

```
    /**
     * Opening saved file.
     * 
     * @param file
     *            - File to be opened
     */

    private void openSavedFile(File file) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Open a file browser and shows the folder which contains the file passed
     * as a parameter.
     * 
     * @param file
     *            - File to be shown in file browser
     */
    public void openFolder(File file) {
        if (file.exists()) {
            file = file.getParentFile();

            Uri selectedUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends a file by email in attachment
     * 
     * @param file
     *            - file to be sent
     */
    private void sendReportByMail(File file) {

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        // setting the type
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

        // the attaching the file
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));

        // the mail subject
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, createEmailSubject());

        // starting email intent with chooser
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, this.getResources()
                .getString(R.string.report_email_chooser)));

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the implicit intent you fire ,any activity is their to handle that fire intent

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        //Gotactivity to handle intent
        startActivity(intent);
    }   else  {
        Log.d(TAG, "No Intent available to handle action");
    }
```